# How to include javascript onclick event in Chtml::link

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I have tried with this code, but it wont work. it works fine when i write it to onmouseover event.

```
echo CHtml::link('Form', 
          array('id'=>'submitButton'),
          array('class'=>'linkClass','onclick'=>'formSubmit();'))


//Javascript
echo CHtml::script("
    function formSubmit(){
         $('#supplier-form').submit();
}");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after hours of searching finally found the answer. 
just add **return false** inside onclick event after you call function name.

```
array('class'=>'linkClass','onclick'=>'formSubmit(); return false;'))
```

and javascript function should be inside `<script>` tags as **rdanusha** mentioned

```
<script>
function formSubmit(){
 $('#supplier-form').submit();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try writing javascript code inside the script tags:

```
<script>
 function formSubmit(){
     $('#supplier-form').submit();
 }
</script>
```